# Output Path to File Content in Views

Tags: views, files

In a view I would like to output just the path to the piece of content where the file is referenced like the below:

```
http://www.example.org/file/1
```

I DO NOT want to link directly to the file itself.

I thought it would be a simple task but most of the fields are adding html (like `<a href="http://www.example.org/file/1">View</a>`).

**I am filtering by a file type of "Video"**.  I have tried adding the below with no success:

```
File: Download Link
File: Edit link
File: Link
File: Path
```

And have also tried using a relationship:

```
Content: Link
Content: Path
```

I have been able to get it working by rewriting the File: File ID field and hard-coding the url with the [fid] as a token, but that's a horrible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to locate another relationship named "File Usage: File"
After that you should be able to add a field type "File: Path". In the field options you can decide how the output is formatted: as server-path (public://yourpath) or as download path.

Comment: I don't want to link directly to the file, I want to link to the piece of content where the file is referenced.